# I didnt recieve ETH transferred from my coinbase wallet

Tags: ether, transfer, coinbase

I've made 2 withdrawals from my coinbase account to transfer my ETH coins to Bybit wallet.

Adress was the same for both transactions, but I've only recieved the first one, although I've used the same steps.

My bybit ETH adress is 0xA8C05ecE9D540C434F63F68DDa8d274618987961

first transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0d297c97bef530270d574d823510c046fd8d6ee0eedd9e21352e3cad21d48afe

second (failed) transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5bb85d49b7b2219f784c8a1003733a1f4ae6179cdc704c4272508a51a348db91

Can someone explain to me if I did anything wrong?

[image]

Comment: Some exchanges do not support deposits from smart contracts. You should contact Bybit wallet customer support to ask how to proceed.

Comment: today i get the same problems. I sent 2 times ETH from Coinbase to Bybit. But only on of them arrived. I called Coinbase for this issue. They say, it´s not there problem. I must speak with Bybit to find a solution. But as you say, in Coinbase there is the same adress like the first one. But accoridng etherscan there is an other adress. I wait for an answer from Bybit.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the second transaction destination, you didn’t transfer ether to your account, you interacted with some CoinBase contract.

Comment: yea, it shows different contact, but on coinbase transactions history it shows the same adress as the first (successful) transaction, so I dont know what went wrong. And I cant contact coinbase support as they dont support my region.

Comment: Can you provide more logs/images ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same thing happen to me.  Coinbase transaction logs show that I input the correct receiving address, but etherscan shows I instead interacted with some contract called Coinbase 10.  Did you ever reach a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing is happening to me. My Coinbase acct shows that the Eth was sent to the correct address. However on etherscan the address it was sent to is different and is labeled “Coinbase 10.” This sure seems like Coinbase is rerouting the transfer to themselves. This is super sketchy to say the least…

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/95011)